# Create default scene with Screen cast keys addon enabled and turned on

Tags: scripting, add-on, screencast

I always want to enable the Screencast keys addon when using Blender. I'm trying to avoid having to remember to turn it on for each new Blender project. I tried turning the checkbox for it on in the N-key side panel and then saving that scene as the default Blender scene. Unfortunately the checkbox doesn't stay turned on in new scenes regardless of that.

Is there perhaps a scripting solution that would allow having the checkbox (that turns Screencast keys display on) always activated in my default Blender scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today there is a property for this (I found it in version 3.7):
[image: Screen cast setting for enable on Blender start]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will keep an addon enabled. You can paste and run it from the Script Editor. Just **replace the string with the name of your addon**. If it's not working then you're probably using the wrong addon name.

```
import addon_utils

addon_utils.enable('shortcut_VUr-master', default_set=True, persistent=True, handle_error=None)
```